# How to draw rectangle(as a background) according to string height and width?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a text and in order to emphasize it I would like to draw a background as a rectangle.

How I try to do it is:

```
string curEdgePhrase = "Cur edge:";
SizeF curEdgePhraseSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(curEdgePhrase, SystemFonts.DefaultFont);
string curEdgeValue = ((int)m_ImageStatForCurSelectedRegion.GetEdginess()).ToString();
SizeF curEdgeValueSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(curEdgeValue, SystemFonts.DefaultFont);

string maxEdgePhrase = "Max edge:";
SizeF maxEdgePhraseSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(maxEdgePhrase, SystemFonts.DefaultFont);
string maxEdgeValue = ((int)m_ImageStatForCurSelectedRegion_MaxValues.GetEdginess()).ToString();
SizeF maxEdgeValueSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(maxEdgeValue, SystemFonts.DefaultFont);

SizeF fullValuesArea = new SizeF(curEdgePhraseSize.Width + curEdgeValueSize.Width /*Width*/,
    curEdgePhraseSize.Height + maxEdgePhraseSize.Height /*Height*/);

///***Draw statistic background rectangle***
Point statisticBackgroundRectStartPoint = new Point(10, 10);
Rectangle statisticBackground = new Rectangle(statisticBackgroundRectStartPoint, fullValuesArea.ToSize());

e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(DrawBorderStatisticBackground, statisticBackground);
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(BrushWhiteSmoke, statisticBackground);
```

So, I am measuring the phrase + value length and width and try to set it as a size of my rectangle

I as a result I am getting something like this

[image]

Do you see this gray rectangle behind the `Cur` word? This is a result...

But what I actually need is

[image]

But this result I am getting if I pass hard coded size..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide the hard-coded code as well? (:

Comment: You're measuring with `SystemFonts.DefaultFont`, but what font was actually used to draw the strings?

Comment: You didn't draw the strings with `DefaultFont`, so why are you using `DefaultFont` to measure them? Use the font object you used to draw the strings to measure them.

Comment: You could use TextRenderer which features a BackColor - If you need the rectangle additionally do use the same one you should use with the string drawing!